# Where can I find the icon for System Settings on the top bar?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-tweak

At the right end of the top bar, there is a power button shaped icon (with the default theme). Where is the icon for this button located? I tried going to my theme folder in `/usr/share/themes` but couldn't find it.

Comment: The icon is /usr/share/help/C/ubuntu-help/figures/system-devices-panel.svg Whether it is used from there or linked from there or something else entirely no clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is `system-shutdown-panel` from the icon theme. The default theme is *Humanity*.

Comment: That looks like the old one, at least in an ubuntu session